# JavaScript alternatives to HTML submit-button, due to JS conflict

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've created a page in which I use a JavaScript validator on the input fields (using a script from javascript-coder.com), but I can't use my  to submit the form, because it's conflicting with a function the validation script is using. My current submit button:

```
<a href="" class="submit" onClick="this.form.submit();">Submit</a>
```

When i use a standard HTML submit button, the script works fine. Is there any other way or function to submit the form without conflicting with the validation script? I'm not confident enough in JS to begin taking the validation script apart.

Please help, and please ask if you need any additional info.
Thanks,

Comment: What does "conflicting with a function the validation script is using" mean? What error do you get, exactly?

Comment: If a standard HTML submit button works, why can't you just use one?

Comment: please explain what is the previous condition, what you added, and what the conflict is. if you just injected a validations script, how does it work? when does validation happen? did you check the console?

Comment: Sorry for the vague explanation, but i need it to be a <a> element for styling purposes. The conflict is just my theory, as I guess some function in the validation script overrides the onClick event. I'll get back when I have investigated further. Thanks for the input so far.

Answer (score 1):

If that is your actual code, you are using the `this` keyword incorrectly. When called from an inline function, this refers to the element is is being called from, i.e. the anchor tag. (See here for more details: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html.) As far as I am aware, you need to submit the form from the form tag.

What you should be using is something like one of these:

```
document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
document.forms[0].submit();
document.getElementsByClassName('submit')[0].submit(); /* not IE8 compatible */
```

Alternatively, if you cannot rely on your element having an ID tag, being in a known order on the page *and* you require IE compatibility, you could continue searching "up" the DOM until you find the form that the button sits in, then submit that:

```
var parentelem = this.parentNode;
while (parentelem.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'form') {
    parentelem = parentelem.parentNode;
    if (parentelem == null) { break; }
}
if (parentelem != null) {
    parentelem.submit()
}
```

Comment: This might help. I'll get back when I have investigated further. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`<a href="" class="submit" onClick="document.form.submit();">Submit</a>`

Answer (score 0):

The validation script uses the onsubmit event of the form to trigger the validations. When you submit the form programatically, the event does to get fired. This should work:

```
<a href="" class="submit" onClick="if(document.yourform.onsubmit()){document.yourform.submit();}">Submit</a>
```

where *yourform* is the ID of your form. See this page for details:

http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml